# JSP page - In a table <TD><input type = text name = "code"></TD>

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jakarta-ee, jsp

[image]

I have created a JSP page with a table containing two columns Code and Description ,the table data is input type="text" name ="code",  the functionality which i have to implement is,if i type the code number the description of the code has to generated automatically from the database could any one please help me

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6489#6489

Answer (score 0):

Why not you create a javafunction that contain a ajax call to your servlet or java file where you can write a code to get description based on code value and return back to jQuery function.

You can trigger jQuery function on "OnChange" event of code input box.

You can get various example and docs over google about ajax request.